# MSSQL - GRANT EXECUTE permission inside stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, permissions, dynamic-sql

**Environment**

SQL Server 2012 (11.0.2100.60)

**Situation**

1. user is [allowed to execute](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/19749/how-do-you-grant-execute-permission-for-a-single-stored-procedure) a number of stored procedure;
2. user is readonly denywrite
3. one of stored procedure has an [EXECUTE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188332.aspx) statement;

**The Problem**
The user can execute all the stored procedure but not the one having the EXECUTE (even if the EXECUTE is trying to read from a view).

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_INJECT_TEST]

@Query varchar(8000)

AS

SET NOCOUNT ON;
EXECUTE(@Query)

GO;
```

**Question**
Is there a specific permission for this situation? Should I switch context and impersonate another USER with all the rights inside the database?

Comment: what is `@Query` (the sql that its trying to execute) ? Permissions are not required to run the EXECUTE statement. However, permissions are required on the securables that are referenced within the EXECUTE string. `even if the EXECUTE is trying to read from a view` - You have to `GRANT SELECT` on the VIEW to the user.

Comment: @Kin. everything works fine now with the **GRANT SELECT**. Many thanks for your help..

Comment: Deny permissions have precedence over grant permissions, have you an explicit deny on an object you are using in the @query?

Answer (score 1):

Try GRANT SELECT on the view and then GRANT EXECUTE on the procedure to the user.
see this

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188371.aspx